# ActiveMQ 5.16.2 Securing Webconsole using HTTPS

Tags: https, activemq-classic, web-console

I have followed [this guide](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console) to secure the ActiveMQ 5.16.2 web console. I made the following configuration in my `jetty.xml`:

1. Per default the authentication setting is `true`, so I just left it like that:

   ```
   <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
   ```
2. I have generated a certificate `amqtest.p12` and moved it into the `conf` folder, i.e.:

   ```
   /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/conf/amqtest.p12
   ```
3. I have enabled the SecureConnector and changed the *keyStorePath* and *keyStorePassword*:

   ```xml
               <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                   <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                   <constructor-arg>
                       <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">

                           <property name="keyStorePath" value="$file:${activemq.conf}/amqtest.p12" />
                           <property name="keyStorePassword" value="changeit" />
                       </bean>
                   </constructor-arg>
                   <property name="port" value="8162" />
               </bean>
   ```

Unfortunately, I receive the following when I try to start ActiveMQ:

```
INFO | Starting Jetty server                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
INFO | Creating Jetty connector                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1ecfcbc9{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /                                                                                                                               
INFO | Listening for connections at ws://amqtest:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600                                                                                                              
INFO | Connector ws started                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (localhost, ID:amqtest-33843-1626808816420-0:1) started                                                                                                                                         
INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org                                                                                                                                                                         
WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/data/kahadb only has 2905 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 2905 mb                         
WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/data only has 2905 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 2905 mb                       
INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/                                                                                                                                                                                       
INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/                                                                                                                                                                     
WARN | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/bin/$file:/home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/conf/amqtest.p12 is not a valid keystore                     
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (localhost, ID:amqtest-33843-1626808816420-0:1) is shutting down                                                                                                                                
INFO | Connector openwire stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
INFO | Connector amqp stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO | Connector stomp stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
INFO | Connector mqtt stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO | Connector ws stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
INFO | Broker Plugin org.apache.activemq.broker.util.DestinationPathSeparatorBroker stopped                                                                                                                                                        
INFO | PListStore:[/home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/data/localhost/tmp_storage] stopped                                                                                                                                                        
INFO | Stopping async queue tasks                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
INFO | Stopping async topic tasks                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
INFO | Stopped KahaDB                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (localhost, ID:amqtest-33843-1626808816420-0:1) uptime 1.539 seconds                                                                                                                            
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.2 (localhost, ID:amqtest-33843-1626808816420-0:1) is shutdown                                                                                                                                     
INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6973b51b: startup date [Tue Jul 20 19:20:15 GMT 2021]; root of context hierarchy                                                                                                     
ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/bin/$file:/home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/conf/amqtest.p12 is not a valid keystore
```

I have generated the cert with an Ansible script provided by my project team. I have also generated another cert with this Ansible script before and it worked to activate ActiveMQ 5.7.0 web console. Thus, I would assume that it was correctly generated.

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used to generate the `amqtest.p12` cert?

Comment: I have generated it with an Ansible script provided by my project team. I have also generated another cert with this Ansible script before and it worked to activate ActiveMQ 5.7.0 Webconsole. Thus, I would asusme that it was correctly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your `jetty.xml`:

```xml
<property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/amqtest.p12" />
```

You have an extra `$file:` in there that's messing it up. You can see this in the error message:

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/bin/$file:/home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/conf/amqtest.p12 is not a valid keystore```
````

Comment: Ah thanks - I have corrected it. But unfortunately now there is another error which pops up:

Comment: ERROR: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
 /home/amquser/apache-activemq-5.16.2/conf/amqtest.p12

Comment: Looks like that's a file permission issue. Ensure the user running the command to start the broker has the proper file access permissions. If you need further help please open a new question.